# Solving a nonhomogeneous recurrence relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations

I was asked to find a first order linear recurrence relation for

$$
a_n=3n^2-2n+1
$$

Here is what I did
\begin{align}\label{1}
a_{n-1} &= 3(n-1)^2-2(n-1)+1\\
&=3(n^2-2n+1)-2n+2+1\\
&=\underbrace{3n^2-2n+1}_{a_n}-6n+5\\
&=a_n-6n+5
\end{align}
Thus, 
\begin{align}
a_n-a_{n-1}=6n-5\tag{1}\label{2}
\end{align}
with $a_0=1$ is a first order recurrence relation for the given sequence.

But I was unable to retrieve the given sequence from this recurrence relation. Clearly, the recurrence is nonhomogeneous. So, its solution is of the form
$$
a_n=a_n^h+a_n^p
$$
Now,
$$
a_n^h=c, \mbox{any constant}
$$
Since $f(n)=-6n+5$o to find a particular solution for the non-homogeneous part, we set
$a_n^p=A_1n+A_0$, where $A_1,A_0$ are constant. Substituting this into (\ref{2}) yield
\begin{align*}
A_1n+A_0-[A_1(n-1)+A_0]&=6n-5\\
A_1 &= 6n-5
\end{align*}
I have tried this again and again but I couldn't tell what is happening? What is wrong with me?

> **Edited**: Let me put it in this way, solve
>   \begin{align}
> a_n-a_{n-1}=6n-5,\ a_0=1.  
> \end{align}

Comment: Try $$a_n^p=A_1n^2+A_0n.$$

Comment: @bof, Why? $f(n)=6n-5$, a polynomial of degree one, shouldn't our particular solution take the same form?

Comment: In your $a_n^p=A_1n+A_0$ the $A_0$ term is useless, because $a_n=A_0$ is a solution of the homogeneous recurrence $a_n-a_{n-1}=0$.

Comment: It's basically the same reason why, in solving the nonhomogeneous DIFFERENTIAL equation $y'-y=(6x+1)e^x$, you would look for a particular solution of the form $y_p=(Ax^2+Bx)e^x$ instead of $y_p=(Ax+B)e^x$.

Comment: Actually, you could turn your recurrence into a differential equation by considering the exponential generating function $$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n!}x^n.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\implies$

$$a_n-a_{n-1}=6n-5\iff6n=?$$
$$ a_{n+1}-a_n=6(n+1)-5\iff6n=?$$

Compare the two values of $6n?$

Comment: @marya, $$3\{n^2-(n-1)^2\}-2\{n-(n-1)\}=3(2n-1)-2=6n-5$$ is correct

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $a_n = p(n)$, a polynomial of degree $m$, then the $m + 1$-th difference of $a_n$, satisfies $\Delta^{m + 1} a_n = 0$.

In this case we have:

$\begin{equation*}
  a_{n + 3} - 3 a_{n + 2} + 3 a_{n + 1} - a_n
    = 0
\end{equation*}$

Get initial values from the polynomial.